# How to convert custom query to CDbCriteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have the following query:

```
select 
    `t`.`id` AS `id`,
    `rm`.`role_id` AS `role_id`,
    `t`.`id` AS `sequence`,
    `t`.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`,
    `t`.`label` AS `label`,
    `t`.`order` AS `order`,
    (case
        when isnull(`rm`.`id`) then 0
        else 1
    end) AS `description`,
    `tb`.`label` AS `parent_label`
from
    ((`tbl_menu` `t`
    left join `tbl_menu` `tb` ON ((`t`.`parent_id` = `tb`.`id`)))
    left join `tbl_role_menu` `rm` ON ((`rm`.`menu_id` = `t`.`id`))) and rm.role_id = $role_id
where
    isnull(`tb`.`label`) 
union select 
    `t`.`id` AS `id`,
    `rm`.`role_id` AS `role_id`,
    `t`.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`,
    `t`.`parent_id` AS `sequence`,
    `t`.`label` AS `label`,
    `t`.`order` AS `order`,
    (case
        when isnull(`rm`.`id`) then 0
        else 1
    end) AS `description`,
    `tb`.`label` AS `parent_label`
from
    ((`tbl_menu` `t`
    left join `tbl_menu` `tb` ON ((`t`.`parent_id` = `tb`.`id`)))
    left join `tbl_role_menu` `rm` ON ((`rm`.`menu_id` = `t`.`id`))) and rm.role_id = $role_id
where
    (`tb`.`label` is not null)
order by `sequence` , `parent_id` , `label`
```

On both queries, on the second left join I have to pass a variable $role_id. Currently, I have this query on a view but if a try passing a criteria condition, the resulting query is

```
select * form menu_links where role_id = $role_id
```

Being menu_links the name of the view. This doesn't give me the result I want. I need a way to add this parameter to this query and transform it into a CDbCriteria in order to pass it to a CGridView. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `CSqlDataProvider` or `CArrayDataProvider`? Both work with `CGridView`.

Comment: @Örs Please post this as an answer so I can mark it. I ended up using the CArrayDataProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider/).

CArrayDataProvider acts as a wrapper around a simple associative array and CGridView won't know the difference. You can even apply pagination, sorting etc. An example showcasing these features can be found in the documentation:

```
$rawData=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tbl_user')->queryAll();

$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'user',
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'id', 'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I give you a simple example you will figure out how to apply it to you case

```
$sql= "select * form menu_links where role_id = :role_id";
$role_id='Something you will get from your could';
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);

// And finally the command you can replace the role id with varibale is
$command->bindParam(":role_id", $role_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$result = $command->queryAll();
```

I hope this was what you were asking.